# CFML Recaptcha JSON Parse Issues

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, recaptcha-v3

So my code has been working for about 1 year and all of a sudden I am getting the follow error from the ReCaptcha Return.

```
"Error","ajp-bio-8014-exec-530","05/16/23","22:17:54","F9CCA4902D7344AC3751382EAE48C4F4","JSON parsing failure at character 1:'C' in Connection Failure The specific sequence of files included or processed is: D:\home\beantownaquatics.com\wwwroot\contact.cfm, line: 8 "

at cfcontact2ecfm2061962498.runPage(D:\home\beantownaquatics.com\wwwroot\inc\contact.cfm:8)

at cfcontact2ecfm299516155.runPage(D:\home\beantownaquatics.com\wwwroot\contact.cfm:45)
```

This is my code for the return.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6Le6210aAA7AAGr8_L2tqNZ2DH-RMP8KRgtPCBGZ"></script>
<!-- CSS only -->
    
<cfif ISDEFINED('FORM.name')> <!--- check if form was submitted and if so run code below --->

    <cfhttp url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=6Le6210aAAAA7C2zZfRTJ-_geqP8bJqK8hUgO9pc&response=#FORM['token']#" result="Response" />
    <cfset Return = deserializeJSON(Response.FileContent) />

    <cfif Return.success IS 'true' AND Return.score GT 0.5> <!--- check if true and if score is greater than 0.5. Run code below if all good. --->
```

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: I hope you are not using the real secret key in this post.

Comment: Nope that was edited

Comment: Did you read the error message? It tells you what the problem is. You're not getting JSON back from the remote site, you're getting a string starting with "Connection failure". You mustn't just assume data from remote sources contain what you want it to. You always need to validate it before charging off an using it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to do something like this since [siteverify endpoint](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify#api_request) is POST method.

```
<cfhttp url="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify" method="post" result="Response">
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="secret" value="#secret#">
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="response" value="#FORM['token']#">
</cfhttp>
```